# JSON from wget outputs extra white space and new line after { at beginning of the output file after

Tags: wget

I am able to wget a URL which already has data in JSON format.  However when viewing the output file there is extra whitespace and newlines, which is causing issues when trying to decode the JSON.

If I just copy and paste the page contents directly from a browser to a .json file the format is perfectly fine.

How can I ensure that wget outputs the page in the exact format it is displayed in, which is json format?

Sorry I have to obscure the actual data due to privacy concerns, but the issue should still be illustrated.

Command used:

```
wget --load-cookies=/home/cookies.txt --header "Accept:application/json" "https://url.com/url/json?" -O output.json
```

Snippet of the output format, notice the multiple lines, I included those from vi just to illustrate.  The actual output does not include those line numbers:

```
  1 
  2     {
  3       "callback": ["callback"],
  4       "attributes": ["xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"],
  5       "types": ["string", "date", "string", "string", "string", "number", "number", "number", "string", "string"],
  6       "records": [["1", "2013-04-03", "blabla", "um", "yes", 1, 0, 0, " 5h 0m", "-1m"], ["2", "2013-04-03", "blabla", "er", "no", 0, 1, 1, " 5h 0m", "-1m"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using `tr -d "[:space:]"` on the entire output and got the file into a format that works.